Fiber length and Zariski's Main Theorem preserving flatness
Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a quasi-finite morphism of irreducible varieties over an algebraically closed field $k$. By "points" $y \in Y$ etc. I mean closed points. A form of Zariski's main theorem states that $f$ factors as
$$
X \overset{j}{\hookrightarrow} T \overset{\pi}{\to} Y
$$
where $j$ is an open embedding $X \subseteq T$ and $\pi$ is a finite morphism. Such a factorization is not unique, though there seems to be an inital object.
Let $d = \deg f$, I am interested in how the fiber length of closed points $y \in Y$ can change. For an finite $k$-scheme $Z$ let $\ell(Z) = \dim_k \mathcal{O}_Z(Z)$ be its length. Then the above factorization gives some insight into how the fibers of $f$ can vary:

$j$ has degree $1$ and for $t \in T$ the fiber is either empty or the reduced point $t \in X \subseteq T$.
$\pi$ has degree $d$ and $y \in Y$ has $\ell(\pi^{-1}(y)) \geq d$ with equality if and only if $\pi$ is flat at $y$ [Liu, Exercise 5.1.25].

So in a way these two morphisms work against each other: For $y \in Y$ the fiber length along $\pi$ may exceed $d$, but then pulling back along $j$ may remove some components of $\pi^{-1}(y)$.
Question 1. If $f$ is assumed to be flat in the first place, then can we arrange $\pi$ to be flat too?
This would imply the inequality $\ell(f^{-1}(y)) \leq d$ for all $y \in Y$ by the previous reasoning. There are other conditions on $X,Y,f$ which restrict how wildly the fiber length or set-theoretic cardinalty can vary, for example normality or Cohen-Macaulayness (e.g. for problems coming from intersection theory). This leads to the second, albeit more vague question:
Question 2. Are there other niceness properties on $X,Y,f$ which can be preserved by ZMT?

The answer to question 1 is negative.
For instance, let $X = \mathbb{A}^2 \setminus \{(0,0)\}$, $Y = \mathbb{A}^2 / \iota$, where $\iota$ is the involution
$$
\iota(x_1,x_2) = (-x_1,-x_2),
$$
and $f$ is the composition
$$
X \subset \mathbb{A}^2 \to \mathbb{A}^2/\iota = Y.
$$
This also gives a natural factorization for $f$ with $T = \mathbb{A}^2$, but $\pi \colon T \to Y$ is not flat. In fact, $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_T$ is a reflexive but not locally free sheaf on $Y$.
Now, if there is another factorization $X \to T' \to Y$ with flat $\pi' \colon T' \to Y$, then $\pi'_*\mathcal{O}_{T'}$ would be a locally free sheaf on $Y$ that away from the singular point of $Y$ coincides with $\pi_*\mathcal{O}_T$. But this is impossible because the reflexive extension of a sheaf is unique.
